# To change sql query without using COALESCE CONCAT CASE STRING in encryption

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, encryption

```
SUBSTRING(COALESCE( 
CASE 
WHEN c.legal_type IS NULL THEN 
  ' ' 
WHEN c.legal_type = 'INDIVIDL' THEN 
  c.ssn 
  ELSE c.tax_identifier 
END 
, ' '), 1, 9), c.birth_date, 
CASE 
WHEN c.legal_type IS NULL THEN 
  ? 
WHEN c.legal_type = 'INDIVIDL' THEN 
  c.first_name 
  ELSE ? 
END 
, c.middle_name, substring(( 
CASE 
WHEN c.legal_type IS NULL THEN 
  ' ' 
WHEN c.legal_type = 'INDIVIDL' THEN 
  c.last_name 
  ELSE c.business_name 
END), 1, 25) surname, ?, c.company, c.operations_area, car.relationship_id, ?, ? FROM s_xref_e49_e30_e33 car INNER JOIN s_customer_e49 c ON car.customer_id = c.customer_id INNER JOIN s_credit_reporting_control_e23 crc ON car.relationship_id = crc.relationship_id INNER JOIN
( 
           SELECT     car.account_id, 
                      b.metro2_base_id 
           FROM       s_metro2_base_e25 b 
           INNER JOIN s_credit_reporting_control_e23 crc 
           ON         crc.credit_reporting_control_id = b.credit_reporting_control_id 
           INNER JOIN s_xref_e49_e30_e33 car 
           ON         crc.relationship_id = car.relationship_id 
           WHERE      b.metro2_report_id = ? 
           AND        b.metro2_base_id >= ? 
           AND        b.metro2_base_id <= ?) m2 ON m2.account_id = car.account_id WHERE car.relationship_type != 'PRIMARY'
AND 
car.has_legal_relationship = 'Y')
```

trying to write query without COALESCE AND SUBSTRING AND CASE CONACT SINCE ENCRYPTON DOESNT SUPPORT THESE

Comment: I want write query without those function either than formatting the sql